# Много фото в разделе иб битрикса, через пользовательское свойство, как вывести?

Tags: битрикс, массивы, php

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите как решить задачку, есть иб, в нем разделы, в разделах элементы.
Нужно при переходе на страницу раздела (list.php) выводить фото которые задаются в разделе через пользовательское свойство(фото, множественное).
Все прописал, в arResult-е по имени (UL_* свойства ) ни путей до файлов ни названий, только цифры.
Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: кто же придумал этот битрикс

Answer (score 3):

Цикл по этим цифрам сделай.

Эти цифры - айдишники файлов ... Получить информацию о файле по `id` можно так :

```
$arFile = CFile::GetFileArray($id);
```